# How do I use Privileged Script in Summer 21?

Tags: locker-service, google-analytics, summer-21

Salesforce mentions a new feature, [Privileged Script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_privileged_script.htm&type=5&release=232), as part of Summer 21:

> With Privileged Script, third-party JavaScript libraries can access
> components in LWR sites. An LWR site encapsulates all of its elements
> in Shadow DOM, which prevents third-party libraries from interacting
> with the components. This script lets libraries, such as Google
> Analytics and Google Tag Manager, bypass Shadow DOM.

This does not tell me how to use the feature.  I have checked in a Summer 21 sandbox, adding an LWC to an LWR Experience, but do not see anything related to "privileged script".

How do I use this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked with our Salesforce team that owns this feature and got an update that the public-facing document would be available on 19/05(Safe Harbor).

In the meantime, the tag to use would be

```
<x-oasis-script src="third_party_library.js"></x-oasis-script>
```

And you can import and export global variables with the imported-global-names and exported-global-names attributes. Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

Documentation is now available regarding this feature: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_privileged_script.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for following up, Swetha.  Can this be used for scripts hosted outside Salesforce?  Does this only work for LWR "Build your own" communities?

Comment: To answer the second question: this doesn't seem to work for Aura (non-LWR) communities.  (Which is consistent with the release docs).

Comment: @Rob I’ll check and confirm

Comment: To answer your question, Yes, but the site would need to have Relaxed CSP enabled and the third-party host would have to be allowlisted (in Settings -> Security & Privacy). See articles [1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_security_csp_scriptlevel.htm&type=5),[2](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_security_csp_allow.htm&type=5)

Comment: When I try and use this in vscode I get this error at deploy time, any ideas?
LWC1512: Missing resource value for @salesforce/oasis

Comment: @RichardClarke Recommend posting this as a new ask along with the steps to reproduce so that the community can suggest better.Thanks